# Broken recursion, when function is called again

Tags: php, function, recursion

I have a recursion issue for my Simpsons pedigree. When I create individual people and then recursion in the peopole.php file and call `$BartSimpson` in index.php, my family tree is listed. But if I also call BartSimpson and HomerSimpson, then nothing will appear for HomerSimpson.

Please do not know what the problem is?

```
<body>
<?php
    require_once ('myclass/People.php');

    $JackieBouvier = new People ('Jackie Bouvier', null, null);
    $mrBouvier = new People ('Mr Bouvier', null, null);
    $penelopeOlsen = new People ('Penelope Olsen', null, null);
    $abrahamSimpson = new People ('Abraham Simpson', null, null);
    $SelmaBouvier = new People ('Selma Bouvier', $mrBouvier, $JackieBouvier);
    $MargeBouvier = new People ('Marge Bouvier', $mrBouvier, $JackieBouvier);
    $HerbSimpson = new People ('Herb Simpson', $abrahamSimpson, $penelopeOlsen);
    $HomerSimpson = new People ('Homer Simpson',$abrahamSimpson,$penelopeOlsen);
    $BartSimpson = new People ('Bart Simpson',$HomerSimpson,$MargeBouvier);

    $BartSimpson -> family();
    $HomerSimpson -> family();
?>
```

```
<?php

class People {

    public $myName;
    public $father;
    public $mother;

    public function __construct ($myName, $father, $mother){
        $this -> myName = $myName;
        $this -> father = $father;
        $this -> mother = $mother;
    }

    public function family(){
        function result($data){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value){
                if (is_object($value)){
                    result($value);
                    continue;
                }
                else if ($value == null){
                    continue;
                }
                echo $value;
                echo ('<br>');
            }
        }
        result($this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Defining a function inside a method is going to cause a fatal PHP error when the method is called for the second time - have you got error reporting enabled?

Comment: I don't have any bug reports allowed, I need to find out how it's done. Thank you for the advice.